# Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to

Tags: java

I'm getting an error like this: `Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to  produktas` ... I'm looking for the solution everywhere, but It seems too difficult for me. Would appriciate any help

My function is:

```
public static produktas[] surasti(produktas G[], int n) {
    try {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        produktas A[] = new produktas[5];
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            System.out.println("Kokio produkto ieskosime?");
            String found = in.readLine();
            for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
                if (found.equals(G[i].gautiPav())) { 
                    A[j] = G[i].gautiPav(); // error line
                }
            }
        } 
        return A; 
    } catch(IOException ie) {
        ie.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

And my array class looks like:

```
class produktas {
    private String pavadinimas;
    private String salis;
    private Double svoris;
    private Double kaina;

    produktas() {}
    produktas(String pav, String salis, double svoris, double kaina) {
        pavadinimas = pav;
        this.salis = salis;
        this.svoris = svoris;
        this.kaina = kaina;
    }

    public String gautiPav() {
        return pavadinimas;
    }
}
```

Comment: this line `if (found.equals(G[i].gautiPav()))` is trying to force a comparison of a `String` to a `produktas`

Comment: @matiaselgart That's not a problem. It will return `false`, but is a valid comparison.

Comment: `A[j] = G[i].gautiPav();` you call gautiPav which returns a string not a produkta

Comment: `A[j] = G[i].gautiPav(); // error line` that line is okay, just this one. When I remove this and try to `A[j] = G[i]` everything is okay

Comment: @Nordiii yeah, I know, but how to solve it? Can't find the solution.

Comment: Can't find the solution?  You're trying to feed a String value into a non-String array.  The solution is to either 1) Make the array a string array: `String[] A = ...`, or 2) feed in the appropriate value type: `A[j] = G[I]`.

Comment: @labasRyta when you want to store the produktas just remove `gautiPav()`

Comment: @Nordiii but then I get a random output like `G[i] = name.produktas@60e53b93` but `G[i].gautiPav() = real_pavadinimas;` outputs it right.

Comment: That "random" output is the default `toString()` output for Object.  If you want your object to be represented as a string differently, then, in produktas: `@Override public String toString() { return pavadinimas; }`

Comment: @Ironcache when I make `String[] A=...` then I can't return the value because it's not produktas

Comment: Then wherever you use A call `gautiPav()`?

Comment: @Ironcache works properly with that, if you can post it as a answer so I can accept it. Thanks

Comment: Don't do [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40725556/type-mismatch-cannot-convert-from-string-to-class-in-java).

Answer (score 2):

A is an array of "produktas". You are trying to assign a string into it, that is the String that is returned by your gautiPav() method.

Are you sure you didn't mean to write this instead?

```
A[j] = G[i]; // error line
```

If you're seeing strings like this: `name.produktas@60e53b93` then you should override the `Object.toString()` method to return a more human readable string, a typical example might look like this. If you're using any modern IDE such as Eclipse there is a helper for this, for Eclipse: Source, Generate toString()...

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.format("[produktas: %s]", pavadinimas);
}
```

Comment: When I do this I get random letters, but not the `pavadinimas`. Output is like `name.produktas@60e53b93`

Comment: @labasRyta then you need to override `toString` in `produktas` -- probably to return `pavadinimas`

Answer (score 0):

Following discussion in the chat, it seems like you want to return A as produktas, but write/view the `guatiPav()` method where you reference A.  You either need to override `toString()` if you want A to be represented differently than a series of "random" output:

```
class produktas {
    private String pavadinimas;
    private String salis;
    private Double svoris;
    private Double kaina;

    produktas() {}
    produktas(String pav, String salis, double svoris, double kaina) {
        pavadinimas = pav;
        this.salis = salis;
        this.svoris = svoris;
        this.kaina = kaina;
    }

    public String gautiPav() {
        return pavadinimas;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return guatiPav(); // or "return pavadinimas;"
    }
}
```

Or you want to call `gautiPav()` directly wherever you're referencing the elements of A.  I highly recommend the latter approach, as an Object's `toString()` should be descriptive of the Object, not a single parameter it is comprised of.